# The group of invertible elements of $\mathbb F_{p}[x]/(x^m)$ is not a cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

I am stuck in a question about finite fields and would like to ask you for some help.

> Given an integer $m\geq 2$ and $p$ a prime number, show that  $(\mathbb F_{p}[x]/(x^m))^{\times}$ (the group of all invertible elements of $\mathbb F_{p}[x]/(x^m)$) is not a cyclic group.

I don't really know how to start. I know a lemma which tells me that for every finite field $\mathbb F_{q}$ with $q$ elements, the multiplicative group of the nonzero elements $\mathbb F_{q}^{\times}$ is cyclic. But I don't think that I should use it here...

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74782/units-in-quotient-ring-of-mathbb-zx) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483642/show-that-mathbbzx-xn1-times-cong-mathbbz-2-mathbbz-times).

Comment: Sorry, but i am still new on MSE. I will correct my mistake. Thank for you editing my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar arguments to those I have already used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74782/units-in-quotient-ring-of-mathbb-zx) give the following group isomorphism: $$(\mathbb F_{p}[x]/(x^m))^{\times}\simeq\mathbb F_p^{\times}\times\mathbb F_p^{m-1}.$$ (This shows that you should assume $m\ge 3$ in order to get a non-cyclic group.) For $m\ge 3$ if you assume that the group of units is cyclic, then $\mathbb F_p^{m-1}$ is also cyclic (or $\mathbb F_p\times\mathbb F_p$ if you like), a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Let $R = \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^m)$, then for any $f(X) = a_0 + a_1X + \ldots + a_nX^n \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$, let $\overline{f}$ denote its image in $R$. Then
$$
\overline{f} \in R^{\ast} \Leftrightarrow (f,X^m) = 1 \Leftrightarrow X\nmid f(X) \Leftrightarrow a_0 \neq 0
$$
Hence, if $\overline{f} \in R^{\ast}$, we may write
$$
g(x) = 1 + a_0^{-1}a_1X + a_0^{-1}a_2X^2 + \ldots + a_0^{-1}a_nX^n
$$
Define
$$
G = \{1 + b_1\overline{X} + b_2\overline{X}^2 + \ldots + b_{m-1}\overline{X}^{m-1}\}
$$
Then, $G$ is a multiplicative subgroup of $R^{\ast}$, and
$$
\overline{f} \mapsto (a_0, \overline{g})
$$
defines an isomorphism
$$
R^{\ast} \cong \mathbb{F}_p^{\ast} \times G
$$
In particular, $|R^{\ast}| = (p-1)p^{m-1}$

1. Note that for any $a \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\ast}$, $a^{p-1} = 1$
2. For any $\overline{g} \in G$, the Frobenius map gives
   $$
   \overline{g}^p = 1 + a_1\overline{X}^p + a_2\overline{X}^{2p} + \ldots + a_{m-1}\overline{X}^{p(m-1)}
   $$
   But since $p > m$, $X^m \mid X^p$, and hence
   $$
   \overline{g}^p = 1
   $$
   Hence,

> The order of any element of $R^{\ast}$ is atmost $(p-1)p$.
>   
>   Since $|R^{\ast}| = (p-1)p^{m-1}$, $R^{\ast}$ cannot be cyclic, **provided $m>2$.**

Added : If $m=2$, then $|G| = p$, and $G$ is cyclic. We also know that $\mathbb{F}_p^{\ast}$ is cyclic. Since $(p,p-1) =1$, it follows that

> $R^{\ast}$ is cyclic if $m=2$

Comment: Thank you very much, dear Prahlad! Now i am going to try to understand every step of your proof :) Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, of course. I was so keen on finding the orders of elements that I didn't think of that!

Comment: I don't think that $1+a_1 X + \dotsc + a_{m-1} X^{m-1} \mapsto (a_1,\dotsc,a_{m-1})$ (you certainly didn't mean $X^p$, which vanishes) is a group homomorphism (unless $m=2$). This already fails for products $(1+a_1 X)(1+ b_1 X)$.

Comment: Hmm. Yes. My brain is refusing to cooperate now. Will just delete that bit, and think about it later.

Answer (score 2):

A cyclic group has at most one subgroup of each order, to it is enough to show that there exists two invertible elements in $F_p[x]/(x^m)$ which have the same order and generate different subgroups. In particular, in a cyclic group there is at most *one* element of order two.

If $p$ is odd, there is a nonzero element $\alpha$ in the field which is different to $1$, and the elements $a=1+x^{n-1}$ and $b=1+\alpha x^{n-1}$ are two different units of order two.

If $p$ is even and $m\geq4$, then $a=1+x^{m-2}+x^{m-1}$ and $b=1+x^{m-1}$ are two different elements of order two.

We are left with $p=2$ and $m=3$, which you can do by hand :-)

Comment: (Notice that in the case I did not do we *do* have a cyclic group)